# How to solve the, "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" error

Tags: java

Error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

How to solve this error?

```
package JAVA_Program;

public class String_reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        String s="hello";
     //   int n=s.length();
        String rev="";
      //  System.out.println(n);
        // My length is 5 ,Hence I started from 5
        try
        {
        for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            rev=rev+rev.charAt(i);
            
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(rev);
      
    }
}
```

Comment: `rev = rev + rev.charAt(i);` should be `rev = rev + s.charAt(i);`

Answer (score 2):

The rev string starts as an empty string.
You are trying to access rev.charAt(i), where i starts from the last index of the original string s. Since rev is empty initially, trying to access any character from it using charAt will throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.
To reverse the string s, you should be looking at the characters in s, not rev.

```
package JAVA_Program;
public class String_reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "hello";
        String rev = "";
        try {
            for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                rev = rev + s.charAt(i);  // Changed from rev.charAt(i) to s.charAt(i)
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(rev);
    }
}
```